# Is there any difference between 'LIMIT 0, 1' and 'LIMIT 1'?

Tags: mysql

I recently stumbled upon example codes, which differed by these notations.

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0, 1
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1
```

The first argument should be considered as the offset if I'm not wrong, the purpose of those two queries is to limit the selection to up the first row of `table`

Is there any negative effect when leaving out the offset/how is it possible to leave it out in the first place? Or did I misunderstood the queries?

Comment: No, you got it right, they are equivalent. This is also: `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0`. But you should really include `ORDER BY` in any query that has `LIMIT`, unless there is a specific reason not to.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) says:

> The `LIMIT` clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the `SELECT` statement. `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. `The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1)`.

The `LIMIT` clause is used in the `SELECT` statement to constrain the number of rows in a result set. The `LIMIT` clause accepts one or two arguments. The values of both arguments must be zero or positive integer constants.

The following illustrates the `LIMIT` clause syntax with 2 arguments:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
LIMIT offset, count;
```

Let’s see what the offset and count mean in the LIMIT clause:

- The `offset` specifies the offset of the first row to return. The offset of the first row is 0, not 1.
- The `count` specifies maximum number of rows to return.

When you use `LIMIT` with one argument, this argument will be used to specifies the maximum number of rows to return from the beginning of the result set.

`SELECT * FROM tbl`
`LIMIT count;`

The query above is equivalent to the following query with the `LIMIT` clause that accepts two arguments:

`SELECT * FROM tbl`
`LIMIT 0, count;`

The `LIMIT` clause often used with `ORDER BY` clause. First, you use the `ORDER BY` clause to sort the result set based on a certain criteria, and then you use `LIMIT` clause to find lowest or highest values.